# R DT Shiny KeyTable select cell/row with Enter

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In R, the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) [KeyTable](https://datatables.net/extensions/keytable/) extension allows to move around the cells with arrow keys.
Is it possible to select the current cell with `Enter` instead of a mouse click?
Thank you in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(datasets)
df <- datasets::mtcars

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    DTOutput('table'), HTML("<br>"),
    textOutput('selected')

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$table <- renderDT(
        df,
        selection = 'single',
        extensions = 'KeyTable',
        options = list(
            dom = 't',
            keys = TRUE
        )
    )
    
    output$selected <- renderText({
        print(rownames(df)[input$table_rows_selected])
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select cells:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

js <- c(
  "table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  if(key == 13){",
  "    cell.select();",
  "  }",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  DTOutput('table'), 
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput('selected')
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    iris,
    selection = 'none',
    extensions = c("KeyTable", "Select"),
    callback = JS(js),
    options = list(
      dom = 't',
      keys = TRUE,
      select = list(style = "multi", items = "cell")
    ),
    server = FALSE
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    input$table_cells_selected
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you also want to deselect:

```
js <- c(
  "table.on('key', function(e, dt, key, cell, originalEvent){",
  "  if(key == 13){",
  "    var selected = dt.cells({selected: true});",
  "    var indices = selected.indexes().toArray().map(JSON.stringify);", 
  "    if(indices.indexOf(JSON.stringify(cell.index())) === -1) {",
  "      cell.select();",
  "    } else {",
  "      cell.deselect();",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});"
)
```